# Running into infinite loop with scanf

Tags: c, validation, user-input, infinite-loop, c89

So I have a bit of code like this (**Just a note this is in C89**):

```
void inputChoice(int* choicePtr)
{
    int choice;
    printf(BLUE "\nINPUT: " RESET);                     /* Print input using the ansi colour code for Blue. */
    scanf("%d", &choice);                               /* Parse the choice. */

    while ((choice < 1) && (choice > 5))                /* Loop until choice is one of the menu options. */
    {
        /* Request for a valid menu option, printing this using the ansi colour code for Red, then resetting back to the default colour. */
        printf(RED "\nMenu Selection must be between (1 and 5) inclusive. \nPlease Re-enter. \n" RESET);
        scanf("%d", &choice);                           /* Parse the choice. */
    }
    *choicePtr = choice;                                /* Set the choice pointer to the valid choice after validation. */
}
```

Which gets the choice. It works fine for integers. But if someone enters anything else, for example a Character. It infinitely loops. 
I want to somehow check for if a character is entered.

One way I tried this was by adding this to check if a character was entered since the integer would be 0 if it didn't scan properly.

Like the below, but that doesn't work either:

```c
scanf("%d", &choice);

while (choice == 0)
{
    printf("Invalid Choice Re-enter.");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
}
```

Comment: Check what [`scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Read user input with `fgets()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
while ((choice < 1) && (choice > 5))
```

is never true since `choice` can't be at the same larger than `5` and  smaller than `1`.

You'll need:

```
while (choice < 1 || choice > 5)
```

`scanf` will try to parse if there is anything on the buffer but will not be able to, it will continue trying causing the infinite loop, because whatever is in the buffer will remain there until it's successfully parsed.

Since `scanf` will return `0` if no arguments are parsed, you can use that information to clear the buffer removing what is causing the infinite loop:

```
int choice = 0;
int c; 
int scanned;
//...
if ((scanned = scanf("%d", &choice)) == EOF){ //check for EOF return
    puts("Unexpected error.");       
    //error treatment is upt to you, I would avoid the loop
    *choicePtr = scanned;
    return;
}
if (scanned == 0) {
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF){}
}
```

in both `scanf`s.

[Live demo](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/BlindGrowingMacrolanguage)

Comment: Just testing for a `0` return value is not enough: if the return value is `EOF`, the value in `choice` was not read and the program should report the unexpected end of file.

Comment: Using `c` as both the return value of `scanf()` (a conversion count) and from `getchar()` ( a character) adds confusion.  Suggest separate variables.  Further , it is unclear why entering a `while` loop when `scanf()` returns `EOF`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, it was just a quick fix, anyway treating EOF separately is better.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I guess I missed the last part of your comment, entering the while loop to give it another try, you think it's best to just abort the operation?

Comment: @anastaciu I think the loop should not  enter on `scanf()` `EOF` return.  On the _rare_ condition of `scanf()` returning an `EOF` due to an input error, the next `getchar()` is not specified that it too must return `EOF`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I see what you mean.

Comment: Curiously  on the condition of scanf() returning an `EOF` due to end-of-file, the next getchar() **is** specified that it too must return `EOF`.  "If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function returns EOF. ... If a read error occurs, the
error indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function returns EOF"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, that is courious, it's nice to know, you see, I was right all along :D

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, one could always juggle with ferror and feof, but the best is just to abort.

Answer (score 1):

Taking remarks from comments into consideration, here is a modified version:

```c
/* reading an input choice between 1 and 5 or -1 on error */
void inputChoice(int *choicePtr) {
    int choice;

    printf(BLUE "\nINPUT: " RESET);       /* Print input using the ansi colour code for Blue. */

    for (;;) {
        int res = scanf("%d", &choice);   /* Parse the choice. */
        if (res == EOF) {
            printf(RED "unexpected end of file\n" RESET);
            choice = -1;
            break;
        }
        if (res == 0) {
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            printf(RED "invalid entry\n" "Please Re-enter.\n" RESET);
            continue;
        }
        if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 5) {
            break;
        }
        /* Loop until choice is one of the menu options. */
        /* Request for a valid menu option, printing this using the ansi 
           colour code for Red, then resetting back to the default colour. */
        printf(RED "\nMenu Selection must be between (1 and 5) inclusive.\n"
               "Please Re-enter.\n" RESET);
    }
    /* Set the choice pointer to the valid choice after validation. */
    *choicePtr = choice;
}
```

Comment: It's too clear, almost dv'd, but in the interest of my moto, uv :)

Comment: I'm also going fot the Sportsmanship badge given that the Unsung Hero is far gone :)

Comment: @anastaciu: as you may have noticed, we have the same motto :)

Comment: We have, that can only mean we are very smart :D Curiously, despite the overwhelming sense that it's a Leonardo da Vinci quote, it's not quite clear it is, [see this nice article](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/04/02/simple/).

Comment: @anastaciu: very interesting! I also love this variant by Antoine de Saint-Exupéry: [*Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38837/where-does-this-translation-of-saint-exuperys-quote-on-design-come-from) or in French: *Il semble que la perfection soit atteinte non quand il n'y a plus rien à ajouter, mais quand il n'y a plus rien à retrancher. ([Terre des Hommes](http://fr.wikiquote.org/wiki/Terre_des_hommes), 1939).* Although the concept of *achieving perfection* seems ambitious.

Comment: Yes, great writer, great adage, even more so, I would argue. You should use that one, it's nicer and from a fellow countryman.